# compare two different lines and columns dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes here:

A:d e,d c,a c,

B:a c,d c,

There are different numbers of line.(No equal lines). If one line in A is match one line in B . We replace the second column of A with the first column of A . So the results should be:

C:d e,d d,a a,

Answer (score 1):

You can do a left `join` of the two data frames on all columns, specify `indicator=True` so the result retains a *_merge* column which indicates if the row in A matches one from B, and update the second column accordingly:

```
A_ = A.merge(B.drop_duplicates(), indicator=True, how="left")

# if the row comes from left only then don't make change, otherwise update the second column 
# with first column value
A_[1] = A_[1].where(A_._merge == "left_only", A_[0])   
A_.drop('_merge', 1)

#   0   1
#0  d   e
#1  d   d
#2  a   a
```

---

```
A = pd.DataFrame([['d','e'],['d','c'],['a','c']])
B = pd.DataFrame([['a','c'],['d','c']])
```

Comment: it showed me below: merge() got an unexpected keyword argument 'indicator'

Comment: What pandas version are you using? the parameter is added on `0.17.0`.

Comment: You might need to assign the result back to `A_` with `A_ = A_.drop('_merge', 1)` or use `inplace` parameter `A_.drop('_merge', 1, inplace=True)`. `A_` should be what you need.

Comment: I use this one A_.drop('_merge', 1, inplace=True) .Thanks so much!